# Failed to write data to json file php

Tags: php, json

I have a simple section in which on click data should be saved to JSON using PHP and Ajax.

on a local machine, everything works fine but on a live server, I get the following error

> Failed to write data to file

No errors whatsoever on a console.
Here is ajax code

```
var params = JSON.stringify({
                                            movies: movies
                                    });
                                    console.log(params);


                                    $.ajax({
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            data: {
                                                    params: params
                                            },
                                            url: 'save_to_json.php',
                                            success: function (data) {
                                                    console.log("successfully")
                                            },
                                            error: function () {
                                                    console.log("sorry , something is wrong");
                                            }
                                    });
```

Here is my PHP file to save data.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['params'])){
    $params = json_decode($_POST['params']);
    // do whatever checks you need on $params to verify valid data

    $success = file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($params));
    if($success === false){
        echo "Failed to write data to file";
        die();
    }else{
        echo "$success bytes were written to the file";
        die();
    }
} else {
    echo "nic";
}

$data=file_get_contents("data.json");
$result=json_decode($data);
?>
```

Why this code is working on local machine but fails to write data to file on 
 live server?

Comment: which php version is on your machine and which on the server?

Comment: does the server have an error log, did you check it (with some detailed information)?

Comment: @jasie PHP Version 7.1.28 on local machine, on live server 
PHP 5.6.32

Comment: make sure the file `data.json` existing on the server and have write permission enabled.

Comment: in this case I suggest you switch to 5.6 on your local machine to check if you get the same error.

Comment: you should check permission of the directory is containing your code file, make sure this directory can be writable

Comment: Check your save directory write permissions or check the owner. On apache2 it mostly is `www-data`.

Comment: Yes now works guys @PhucLam